# Steps to use angular leaflet directive in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I would like to use `angular-leaflet-directive` in my `typescript` project? what are the steps involved in this process?
Do I need type definition file for `angular-leaflet-directive`? or just having typescript definition file for `leaflet` is enough?
Can somebody outline the steps how to use `angular-leaflet-directive` in a `typescript` project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any angular directive in typescript is no different than in regular JS.

Remember, that `.ts` files are transpilled into valid `.js` files. Every classic `.js` script can be sucessfully used along with `Typescript`.

The only thing `Typescript` can give you, when using third party libraries is static typing and intellisense. If you don't need it, then `Typescript` won't give you anything. And you won't need it, since you use this directive in your `HTML` not directly in scripts.

Comment: reason I ask is that - to avoid these (http://www.baconapplications.com/extending-interfaces-of-existing-typescript-definitions/) kind of situations